# How to get back to default tensorflow version on google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I did not know that `tensorflow` and `keras` were installed by default on the machine used by Google Colab. And I installed my own versions. But it was buggy. So I decided to go back to the previous versions. I did:

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.6.0
```

and

```
!pip install keras==2.1.5
```

But now, when I do `import keras`, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'name_scope'
```

**Nota**:
I asked a friend to know the default `tensorflow` and `keras` versions, and he gave me these:

```
!pip show tensorflow  # 1.6.0
!pip show keras  # 2.1.5
```

So I suspect, my installations were wrong somehow. What can I do so I can import `keras` again ?

Comment: Can't you just simply re-connect to a new runtime? That should set the installation back to the defaults.

Comment: Sadly, no. I just tried to be sure but installing a new version of `keras`, say `2.0.0` on a colab notebook will change the `keras` version for all my notebooks.

Comment: Interesting, I can confirm that. However, it will get reset after being disconnected for a certain time, seen that in other instances. Not sure what the underlying mechanic is or how long you need to wait, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get back to the default versions, I had to restart the VM.
To do so, just do:

```
!kill -9 -1
```

Then, wait 30 seconds, and reconnect.

I got the information by opening an issue on the [github repository](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/115).